# Difference between word ptr d, and word ptr + 2 for assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

What is the difference between:

1st

```
mov cx, word ptr d
```

-loads a word size value of d into cx

2nd

```
mov cx, word ptr d + 2
```

-what does that + 2 do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MASM/TASM syntax (which your code seems to be using), `mov cx, word ptr d` means the same thing as `mov cx, word ptr [d]`. So `mov cx, word ptr d + 2` is the same as `mov cx, word ptr [d + 2]` (i.e. it's reading a word from the address of `d` plus 2 and storing the value in `cx`).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misremembering, it adds an offset to the address `d`.